# How can I pass a property of type List from View to Controller and back again?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a very simple form with only a dropdown control and a submit button.  The dropdown will only ever contain anywhere from one to maybe 10 entries.  What I would like is to be able to pass the List that populates this dropdown to the controller in case the flow of control requires that I bounce right back to the form (eg. Bad selection - or something ... ).  Ideally I could then repopulate the dropdown without having to query for the data again.

Here's some stripped down code to describe what I'm working with.

**The Model**

```
public class AppointmentViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The Id of the appointment request record.
    /// </summary>
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public bool Declined { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The booking confirmation ID
    /// </summary>
    public string ConfirmationID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Code to indicate why booking failed / success is 100.
    /// </summary>
    public string BookingCode { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Contains all possible purposes for an appointment.
    /// </summary>
    public List<SelectListItem> Purposes { get; set; }
}
```

**The View** In the view I thought I'd be able to simply store the List in a hidden input field but the 'value' of the field ends up being the List type.  The html source looks like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Purposes" name="Purposes" value="System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem]" />
```

As you can see there are no item values from my list control.  Only the type of data it contained.

```
@model AppointmentViewModel  

<div class="row  mx-auto" style="width:50%">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post" asp-controller="Booking" asp-action="SelectPurpose" asp-route-searchType="1">

            <input type="hidden" asp-for="Purposes" />

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Go ahead and select a good ol' purpose!</label>
                <select asp-for="PurposeId" asp-items="Model.Purposes"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Purposes" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check Availability</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

When this form is submitted to the controller, the Model does contain the selected purpose ID but the List of Purposes is a length of 0.  It isn't null but it doesn't contain anything either.  So, if the user is bumped back to the View the dropdown list is empty.

How can I pass that list to the controller so I can pass it back again (or potentially pass it forward to a different form)?

Comment: One thing you can actually do is to "cache" the list as a json object in javascript... and "hand craft" the postback using perhaps jquery and then you can model the object to your liking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working demo like below:

1.Model:

```
public class AppointmentViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool Completed { get; set; }
    public bool Declined { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationID { get; set; }
    public string BookingCode { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Contains all possible purposes for an appointment.
    /// </summary>
    public List<SelectListItem> Purposes { get; set; }
}
```

2.View:

```
@model AppointmentViewModel
<div class="row  mx-auto" style="width:50%">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div>
                @{ int i = 0;}
                @foreach (var x in Model.Purposes)
                {
                    <input type="hidden" name="model.Purposes[@i].Text" value="@x.Text" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="model.Purposes[@i].Value" value="@x.Value" />
                    i++;
                }
            </div>
            @*<input type="hidden" asp-for="Purposes" />*@

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Go ahead and select a good ol' purpose!</label>
                <select asp-for="Id" asp-items="@Model.Purposes"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Purposes" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Check Availability</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

3.Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new AppointmentViewModel()
    {
        Purposes = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Value1", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Value2", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Value3", Value = "3"},
            new SelectListItem{Text = "Value4", Value = "4"}
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(AppointmentViewModel model, int Id)
{
    //do your stuff...
    return View(model);
}
```

4.Result:
[image]